# Как узнать оставшееся время работы запроса в Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть неких запрос, который успешно запущен и хотелось бы занть, сколько он еще будет отрабатывать.

Вроде как в базе есть некие стандартные оракловые таблицы, по которым можно отследить статистику работы запроса, в том числе узнать сколько осталось времени до финиша запроса.

Или может кто знает как при помощи инструментов, таких как `Toad` или `PL/SQL Developer`, можно посмотреть долго ли осталось запросу еще работать.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в предоставлении инфы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [v$session_longops](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/V-SESSION_LONGOPS.htm#REFRN30227) или `gv$session_longops` (если у вас RAC - Real Application Cluster):

```
select  /*opname, target,*/ 
        sid||','||serial#||',@'||inst_id as kill_sess,
        elapsed_seconds as "elaps/s", 
        time_remaining as "remain/s", 
        round((sofar*100)/totalwork) "%done", 
        to_char(start_time,'hh24:mi:ss') as started,
        sql_id||' ('||sql_plan_hash_value||')'as "sql_id (plan_hash)", 
        message  
from    v$session_longops
where   time_remaining > 0
order   by start_time desc;
```

> `V$SESSION_LONGOPS` displays the status of various operations that run
>   for longer than 6 seconds (in absolute time). These operations
>   currently include many backup and recovery functions, statistics
>   gathering, and query execution, and more operations are added for
>   every Oracle release. To monitor query execution progress, you must be
>   using the cost-based optimizer and you must:

- Set the TIMED_STATISTICS or SQL_TRACE parameters to true
- Gather statistics for your objects with the DBMS_STATS package

---

Если вам известен SQL_ID:

```
undef sql_id
set pagesize 0 echo off timing off linesize 1000 trimspool on trim on long 2000000 longchunksize 2000000

select 
   DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR(sql_id=>'&&sqlid',report_level=>'ALL') as report 
from dual;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. НО запустил ваш запрос и не обнаружил в нем моей сессии с запущенным запросом. Также при помощи Toad захожу в Session Browser, нахожу свою сессию, захожу во вкладку Long Ops, но ничего не обнаруживаю. Что это значит, что мой запрос завис, или оптимизатор думает, как его оптимизировать? Как-то в таком случае можно спрогнозировать время выполнения запроса? Спасибо.

Comment: А я понял, если нет Full Scan таблицы, значит в v$session_longops ничего не видно. Собственно в плане запроса отсутствует Full Scan, соответвенно я ничего не вижу. Другие способы/таблицы есть, где можно посмотреть информацию о запросе?

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. SQL_ID определил, и нужную информацию для себя получил. Еще раз спасибо за помощь.